How to setup Airflow avaliable by https://host_ip_address:8080?
I've got Airflow v. 2.9.2 on my Vurtuial Private Server.
But I can't access it by https://host_ip_adress:8080
What I need to make it available by ip address?
Now I've installed Airflow 2.9.2 according documentation.
Fetching docker-compose.yaml:
curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.9.2/docker-compose.yaml'

mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins ./config
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env

docker compose up airflow-init

Docker-compose.yaml changes:
  #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.9.2}
  build: .

Dockerfile:
FROM apache/airflow:2.9.2
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} -r requirements.txt

requirements.txt:
clickhouse_connect==0.7.8
ujson==5.10.0

And at the end docker up:
docker compose -f /opt/beget/airflow/docker-compose.yaml up -d --build

Now Airflow is up:

Docker Compose version v2.27.0
Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-112-generic x86_64)
Folder with Airflow:


Which ip address? What about https? Where do you install and generate or buy certificates? What I need to make it available by ip address? Is a very, very broad question. You need to run a service that listens on that ip address and on that port, and that ip address has to be resolvable from the device you are connecting from. What is the specific error you are getting? Please do not post images of text - please post text as text into the question. Kindly read the docker-compose.yml file and try to understand it, as all configuration is there.

My understanding is that the docker-compose files from airflow is not "one fit all" solution. You are expected to tinker with it. The docker-compose file contains a ports: redirection - the speicifc ip address and it's availability depends on your specific system and network setup. Refer to your docker daemon configuration and docker documentation on ports:

I'm trying to start Airflow for my first time, maybe I could suggest which documentation pages I should read to get how I should read. Cause I got ready to use Airflow 2.8.2 (installed automatically with docker) which variable by https://host_ip_adress:8080. I just trying to up new version of Airflow with docker.
